# Command to see the logical volume path, device mapper path and its corresponding dm device path

Tags: linux, lvm

Currently I am using this laborious command

```
lvdisplay | awk '/LV Path/ {p=$3} /LV Name/ {n=$3} /VG Name/ {v=$3}  /Block device/ {d=$3; sub(".*:", "/dev/dm-", d); printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", p, "/dev/mapper/"v"-"n, d}'
```

Would like to know if there is any shorter method to get this mapping of combined output (lvpath, **/dev/mapper/** and **/dev/dm/*** ), possibly a single command.

Comment: lvs -o may be an option

Comment: Note that `/dev/mapper/vgname-lvname` is not correct for vg or lv names that contain dashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man pages for lvdisplay.

Aside from the path to the block device the data can be reported directly from

```
lvdisplay -C -o "lv_path,lv_dm_path,lv_kernel_minor"
```

If you execute

```
lvdisplay -C -o " "
```

Then lvdisplay will list all of the available fields.

Comment: Hi. lvextend should be used in "Path" or "DMPath"?

Answer (score 0):

man lvdisplay says "lvs(8) is a preferred alternative that shows the same information and more, using a more compact and configurable output format."

Hence:

```
lvs -o "lv_path,lv_dm_path,lv_kernel_minor"
```